# Why do horizontal translations of graphs of $\log(x)$ have "gaps" in them?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, calculator

> Why do horizontal translations of graphs of $\log(x)$ have "gaps" in them?

For example, the graph of $y = \log(x+2)$ has a gap at around $y = -15.3$. Aren't logarithmic functions supposed to be continuous?

[image]

On a further note, the graph of $y = \log(x)$ appears to end at a finite point (in the $y = -200$s in Desmos). Why is this the case?

Comment: It's just a glitch/bug of a program that produced this picture.

Comment: Is that graph supposed to be log(x-2)? Or did you mean to say log(x+2)? In either case, the shape doesn't look quite right. See [this plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryMkv0cjJT9eo0DbS1FHQ0DXSUTA0ALISiwtSk0viixJLMvNtDTUB8RYL2g==&lang=sage). As $x\to 0, \log(x) \to-\infty$ so a plotter has to stop somewhere.

Comment: I guess you're using the base 10 logarithm, which looks like [this](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryMkv0cjJT9eo0DbSUTA00NRR0NCFsUoyk7OLbTUMgVwgL70oMyUnMy-12FYpNzErv0hJRyGxuCA1uSS-KLEkM9_WUBMARh4W1A==&lang=sage) in Sage.

Comment: Please put the edit in the body of your Question, not buried in a Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is a result of the limitations of Desmos as a graph plotting software, probably due to how the graph is rendered. This issue is also unique to each particular zoom level. For instance, here is that function at a different zoom:[image: Plot of y = ln(x+2)]

Comment: It's interesting that desmos would have a "glitch" like that. I have never run into that problem before. Thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you mean $y = f(x) = \log(x+2)$, so that at $x = -2$ the function is undefined and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -2^+} f(x) = -\infty$.

In reality, $f(x)$ is a continuous and in fact surjective function, meaning that every $y$-value is obtained by some $x$.  This means a perfect drawing should have no gap as you notice.

**However**, for very large negative $y$, the solution to $y = f(x)$ will be **very** close to $-2$.  For example, for $y = -15$, we solve $-15 = \log(x+2)$ to get $x = e^{-15}-2 = -1.99999969\ldots$; this means that **the solution to $f(x) = -15$ will likely not be found by a grapher.** Assuming that the grapher functions by plotting points $(x, f(x))$ for $x$ uniformly spread on a grid, ie $x = a + k(b-a)/n$, where $a$ and $b$ are the left and rightmost end-points and $n$ is the number of points to be drawn, and assuming $a$ and $b$ are integers, we would not be near such a point unless $n$ is on the order of $1/ .0000003059 \approx 3$ million values.  In other words, when plotting the points $(x, f(x))$, the grapher doesn't see any value of $f(x)$ near $-15$ and so does not plot any such point simply because the **granularity** of is the chosen $x$ values to plot not fine enough.  For example, the algorithm might graph the function based on a table like

\begin{align*}
(-2.01, \text{undefined}) \\ (-2, \text{undefined}) \\ (-1.99, -5.6\ldots)\\
(-1.98, -3.91\ldots )\end{align*} which skips over

$$(-1.99999969\ldots, -15)$$ entirely.
Of course, if some more sophisticated plotting algorithm is used this argument does not apply; I don't know about other curve-drawing algorithms so I will not venture a guess in that case.

Comment: I had no idea that a problem like that would ever occur on desmos since I have never run into this situation before. However, this explanation makes so much sense. Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: @Soheil Thank you, fixed it.