# Why does Desmos not render graphs like this properly?

Tags: desmos

I was trying to show some students the graph of $y=4- \ln (2-x)$ today on Desmos.

[image]

Unfortunately we can see from the picture below that the graph does not render correctly around the asymptote and appears to 'stop' at around $y=40$. This same behaviour happens when we try to plot the graph on a graphical calculator so I wonder what it is about this graph that is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably it's only working to finite precision and just not calculating the relevant values of $x$. You can figure out what those values are by substituting $y = 40$ and solving for $x$.

Comment: Indeed the relevant value of $x$ is about $2.32\times*10^{-16}$ less than $2$, which is right around machine precision.

Comment: See my answer to a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143993/why-do-horizontal-translations-of-graphs-of-logx-have-gaps-in-them/4144017#4144017).

Comment: You can use [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator) and get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like (almost) everything, Desmos is *not perfect*.

The "*term*" for this is **unresolved detail**, as Desmos calls it. This is what an official [Desmos FAQ](https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/202529079-Unresolved-Detail-In-Plotted-Equations) officially says about this:

> Sometimes the calculator detects that an equation is too complicated to plot perfectly in a reasonable amount of time. When this happens, the equation is plotted at lower resolution.

For more on Desmos, I answered a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769278/desmos-and-wolfram-alpha-contradict-is-1x-ge-1-x-true-for-all-x/4769300#4769300). Also, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/softwaregore/comments/p7gnqi/so_i_was_writing_out_some_equations_on_desmos_and/) is a slightly less trusted website (Reddit) but it does have a great example of what you were experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for this and for the term, will know what to say when students ask this again.